# Using the Github Gist API from Haskell

Tags: http, api, haskell, gist

First of all, I've never really used APIs before, and I've never used the HTTP library in Haskell. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, so maybe somebody who knows can help.

I'm using what I can read of this: http://github.com/defunkt/gist/blob/master/gist.rb, namely the write method, to write this:

```
req = postRequest "http://gist.github.com/gists/new"

testPost = simpleHTTP $ req {rqBody = urlEncodeVars 
                                      [("login", "Raynes"),
                                       ("token","<removed>"),
                                       ("file_ext[gistfile1]",".hs"),
                                       ("file_name[gistfile1]","testfile"),
                                       ("file_contents[gistfile1]","main = putStrLn \"Hello, world!\"")]}
```

When ran, testPost gives this output:

```
Right HTTP/1.1 302 Found 
Server: nginx/0.7.61
Date: Sun, 29 Nov 2009 17:13:51 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: close
Status: 302 Found
Location: http://gist.github.com/gists/new
X-Runtime: 1ms
Content-Length: 98
Set-Cookie: _github_ses=BAh7BiIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNoSGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7AA%3D%3D--884981fc5aa85daf318eeff084d98e2cff92578f; path=/; expires=Wed, 01 Jan 2020 08:00:00 GMT; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

As far as I know, the Location should be a link to the new Gist. However, no new Gist is made. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. There is basically no documentation for the Gist API, and the only thing I can assume is that I'm not translating the Ruby correctly. Like I said, I've never really used the HTTP library before.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain which output you expected instead (or which output you would have liked)?

Comment: It's not doing anything at all as far as I can tell. The location field is (as far as I know) supposed to be a link to the new Gist, however, no Gist is made. I'm absolutely baffled. This seems like it should be easy. :\

Comment: Maybe you have some errors with post vars. Follow redirect, send session cookie and read html page you receive. It can contains some error messages.

Comment: I've been doing the same thing myself recently, and I found http-enumerator to be a life saver for use with Aeson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself after reading an example of using Network.Browser.browse.

```
req = "http://gist.github.com/gists"

testPost = do
  (uri, rsp) <- Network.Browser.browse $ do
                  setAllowRedirects True
                  request $ formToRequest $
                          Form POST (fromJust $ parseURI req)
                                   [("file_ext[gistfile1]",".hs"),
                                    ("file_contents[gistfile1]","main = putStrLn \"Hello, world!\""),
                                    ("login","Raynes"),
                                    ("token","removed")]
  return uri
```

Answer (score 0):

Your POST url is wrong, according to source is should be http://gist.github.com/gists [source](http://github.com/defunkt/gist/blob/master/gist.rb#L29)

Comment: That was an accident on my part. I was experimenting and forgot to remove that.